# Mysql fieds list error

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have one mysql query but when i'm trying to work showing me that error

**Unknown column 'ps_address.phone_mobile' in 'field list'**

Mysql Query is

```
SELECT
ps_orders.id_customer,
ps_customer.firstname,
ps_customer.lastname,
ps_customer.email,
ps_orders.total_paid,
ps_orders.date_add,
ps_address.phone_mobile
FROM
ps_orders JOIN ps_customer on  ps_orders.id_customer = ps_customer.id_customer
WHERE ps_address.id_customer=ps_orders.id_customer and
ps_orders.total_paid > 1 
AND ps_orders.id_customer IN (
SELECT
ps_orders.id_customer
FROM
ps_orders
GROUP BY
ps_orders.id_customer
HAVING
COUNT(1) < 2
  )
```

Comment: but i have that column

Comment: But you are not selecting from the table. Change it to `FROM ps_address, ps_orders`

Comment: @Jan Thank you so much that is fix my problem

Comment: @Jan but that time making duplications on numbers still have problem i thing about join for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specifiy the table you're selecting FROM. So if the column exists, here's the updated query (abbreviated):

```
SELECT
    ps_orders.id_customer,
    ps_customer.firstname,
    ps_customer.lastname,
    ps_customer.email,
    ps_orders.total_paid,
    ps_orders.date_add,
    ps_address.phone_mobile
FROM
    ps_address, ps_orders
JOIN
   ps_customer on ps_orders.id_customer = ps_customer.id_customer
WHERE
   ps_address.id_customer=ps_orders.id_customer AND
   ps_orders.total_paid > 1 AND 
   ps_orders.id_customer IN (...)
```

Comment: SELECT
ps_orders.id_customer,
ps_customer.firstname,
ps_customer.lastname,
ps_customer.email,
ps_orders.total_paid,
ps_orders.date_add,
ps_address.phone_mobile
FROM ps_address, ps_orders JOIN ps_customer on  ps_orders.id_customer = ps_customer.id_customer
WHERE ps_address.id_customer =ps_orders.id_customer AND ps_orders.total_paid > 1 AND ps_orders.id_customer IN (
SELECT ps_orders.id_customer
FROM ps_orders
GROUP BY ps_orders.id_customer
HAVING COUNT(ps_orders.id_customer) < 2)

Comment: That is fix my all problem thank you so much for help my friend. @Jan

Answer (score 0):

> The column does simply not exist?

Your script has syntax error. Column name "1" does not really exists in

> COUNT(1) < 2

must be:  *COUNT(**column_name**)* < 2 
or *COUNT(*)*  <2

---

COUNT(ps_orders.id_customer) < 2

Answer (score 0):

This syntax error means, you do not have this column **"phone_mobile"** in this table **"ps_address"**.

Comment: I have this table problem is i was need to add ps_adress to from that is fix my problem

Comment: @ZgrKARALAR: did not get your point friend, just check your table, and if this column not available just add it.